# Creating a file with a single space and no newline

Tags: shell, echo

For testing purposes I am trying to create a file that only contains a single space character. However it seems most methods I use add a new line at the end.
I've tried using vi and nano for editing.

Also tried `echo " " > file` but nothing so far

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this would be `printf ' ' > file`. Even [POSIX recommends using `printf` in favour of `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html). Note that either of both of `echo` and `printf` may be built in to your shell. Run `type echo printf` to see how things are on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
echo -n " " > file
```

The `-n` option suppresses the (default) newline.

If your system's implementation of `echo` does not recognize the `-n` option, then another alternative is:

```
printf " " > file
```

Comment: why am I getting `-n` in my command output: `#echo -n " " > file2`                                                                                                            `#cat file2
-n`

Comment: Check the manual entry.  Does your version of `echo` support the `-n` option?

Answer (score 1):

You can try also...

```
printf " " > fileName
```

For more information : man printf

Comment: Use `>` instead of `>>`. If the file already has content, you need to truncate instead of append.